# Icon colors are difficult to see

Tags: theme

I changed a lot of items individually in the Edit>Preferences>Themes options to make it easier for my deteriorating vision. Somehow these changes made the icons for the toolbars on the right funny colors, vary pale with turquoise accent colors.

Nothing I set under the Icons section has that turquoise color, so the shading and color come from something else apparently. I have been reading that the icons are supposed to hard wired into the program and monochromatic, but something has changed them, somehow. Since I don't know what changed them and I can't find that turquoise color on any other items I set.

I did find I could set the background of the icon to black and then I could see them, but my vision does better seeing black items on white backgrounds so if there is any way to adapt these icons on the toolbar, I would like to know.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about these icons:

[image]

You need to change the Themes>User Interface>Tab Inner, Selected and Outline colors.

Edit: OK, you mean these:

[image]

Unfortunately, those are built from source. See [this link](https://developer.blender.org/T64177#787946) if you are interested in trying to modify them.

You can change the background and border though by going to User Preferences>Themes>User Interface>Tool and changing the Outline and Inner Options.

Comment: I mean the ones on the toolbar which defaults to the left on the Object mode and Edit Mode of the 3D Viewport. (I am not sure how to add pictures to this Blender.stackexchange, but I have one if you will tell me how to.) I can change the background of these icons, but I have to leave it black because the icons are whitish. I have low vision and do best with high contrast (or bright color) things when they are small, so I was hoping to find a way to make them black on white which is the easiest for my vision. I'm making do with white on black, but if there is way to reverse it, I 'd like  that.

Comment: Please see edited answer.

Comment: Thank you! Not quite brave enough to try recompiling it, though. I'll have to make do and hope there are changes later.

Comment: Funny you should say that. The Blender live stream today showed that in 2.83, the toolbar icons will automatically switch from dark to light based on the background color. It's going to be a little while, but it's coming.